# Why final variables cannot be used in switch statements?

Tags: java, switch-statement

When I type the following code into Eclipse, it complains that "case expressions must be constant expressions". If the array is marked `final`, its contents must be constant. Why is this invalid?

```
final String[] match={"a","b","c"};
switch (switchVar) {
case match[0]: /* Eclipse complains here about nonconstant switch */
    System.out.println("Matches");
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("No Match");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing constant about an array.  Its contents may be mutated at any time.  The *reference* will say the same, but `match[0]` could be something different at any point in time.

You *have* to use a constant value; one that's guaranteed not to change.  Things like enums, primitive literals (and their boxed counterparts), and `String` literals are guaranteed not to change through this process, and are valid for use.

This *does* mean, however, that you can use a variable which is marked `final` and isn't mutable, though.  Since array types *are* mutable, it doesn't work out as well - even if you reassign it to a `final` variable.  You have to declare the literal.

Here's a simple snippet below, revising your existing code:

```
String switchVar = "a";
final String matchZero = "a";
switch (switchVar) {
    case matchZero: // valid since there's no way matchZero can ever be mutated
        System.out.println("Matches");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("No Match");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Your quotation does not 'reinforce this point'. The grammar does: `SwitchLabel:
case ConstantExpression :
case EnumConstantName :
default : `. Your quotation is about what goes inside the switch-expression itself, in the `switch` part.

Comment: @EJP:  That could read a bit confusingly; I agree.  I've reworded it.

Comment: 'Confusingly'? It was irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

> If the array is marked final, its contents must be constant.

This is an incorrect understanding. A final variable only prevents new instances of the array being created, but it does not prevent the contents of the array being altered. I can do this with your existing code and it will be valid:

```
    final String[] match = {"a", "b", "c"};        
    match[0] = "b"; // CHANGE HERE
    switch (switchVar) {
        case "a": //Fixing this to make it compile
            /* Eclipse complains here about nonconstant switch */
            System.out.println("Matches");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No Match");
            break;
    }
```

To make the code compile and to use the switch statement, you need to be using constants. So either declare constants or an in place string would make it work.

```
    final String[] match = {"a", "b", "c"};        
    switch (switchVar) {
        case "a": // CHANGE HERE
            /* Eclipse complains here about nonconstant switch */
            System.out.println("Matches");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No Match");
            break;
    }
```

The reason why this is is simply because the [The Java Language Specification on switch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) makes the assumption that all switch statements works on constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

the point of your question is 'final',

```
final String[] match = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

this means the address of array match can not be changed, but it not means the values of array macth can not be changed.

And case statement need a constant value